# Want to update only gridView but whole page is being refreshed

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

Please Help me out.... I am new to ASP.net programming..
I have a a main page and on that page i have a button  **Button1** , now on clicking that button a panel is supposed to popup.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modelPopupExtender1"
     CancelControlID="Btcancel"
    PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Button1"  
    Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModelPopupBG" 
    runat="server" DropShadow="True" 

    >
```

Now in **Panel1** i have 2 image buttons. 1) to search out the entered data(i am using a textbox for entry) and fill the data into the **gridview1**    and 2) to cancel the popup.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >  
<div class="HelloWorldPopup">    
<div class="PopupBody">
<div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader"><b ><p style="margin-top: 10px">  Selection Panel</p></b></div><div id="UpperBody">  
    <table border="1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <th >
        <asp:TextBox ID="entry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th><th>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="dropdowns">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Name"  >
        </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Text="Address" >
        </asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem  Text="Telephone">
        </asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></th><th>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="Btok" runat="server" onclick="Btok_Click"  ImageUrl="~/images/isearch.png"/>
       </th>
        <th  >
       <asp:ImageButton ID="Btcancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif" />         
       </th>           
        </tr>                   
    </table>
    </div>   
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        style="margin-top: 11px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
        BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" 
        GridLines="None" Width="100%"      onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="telephone" HeaderText="Telephone" />
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Select" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
    </asp:GridView>


</div>
```

everything is fine but only problem i am facing is that the whole page is being refreshed instead of just the  **gridview1**  while i just want to refresh the gridview1 data when i click on **BtOk**

I guess using updatePanel for that gridView can sort things out for me.. but don't know how ...
What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the answer - UpdatePanel (that's one approach)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="GridUpdatePanel">
<ContentTemplate>

   <asp:GridViewID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Simply create an UpdatePanel tag, and put your GridView between the `ContentTemplate`

Comment: which type of notification is coming?

Comment: Actually i've added a class inside my program which has a javascript method which simply shows any string passed as  message..

    'public class MessageBox
    {
        public static void Show(string message, Control owner)
        {

            Page page = (owner as Page) ?? owner.Page;

            if (page == null) return;
            page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(owner.GetType(), "ShowMessage", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", message));
        }'